# Ginger bug problem

Tags: beer, ginger

I have set up a 1 gallon brew using brewers yeast.
I have also made my own bug starter and also purchased one.

After 4 days my own starter is going well and smells very strongly of yeast.

The purchased one however shows no sign of bubbling but has developed a strong sour/yeast smell plus something else which may be alcohol.
I am not sure what is going on.

My gut feeling is to go with the purchased one as it has the required yeast and bacteria.
My own starter i do not know what bacteria are present but i will try a small brew.
I saw the post about the ginger bug smell but am really not sure if it is working.

The brewing yeast one is good but i cannot give it to the kids, currently it is 5.2% ABV , i was wondering if i could dilute it 1:1 then let the bug do its work if i can get it going.

I had it on the kitchen window though and i see elsewhere that light is a bad idea for this.

EDIT, as suggested.

Third batch was a winner.
Recipes out there seem to be vague.
So i have decided to weigh.
10 to 25 g of shredded ginger per litre.
25g is particularly fiery though but suits my taste.
1/2 lemon per litre, if making ginger lemonade it is best to leave a head space when bottling and add extra lemon later.

If all the lemon goes in at the start i end up with something that just tastes sour not lemony.
The teaspoon of bug i started with was not enough, although i have managed to grow it now. It is much slower to develop than brewing yeast.
For the mother i used boiled yeast and a little nutrient.
I also added a crushed multivitamin tablet which does appear to have improved the starter culture significantly.I do not use these when brewing though.

Comment: What sort of bug starter was purchased? What did it physically look like? Ginger beer bug is a SCOBY that looks like small grains of opaque mush. It can be bought dried and rehydrated but after hydration it looks like small white grains. Anything else is probably not a SCOBY and is more likely a (wild) yeast. When the SCOBY is active it bubbles vigorously.

Comment: It was supplied live looking like bits of white jelly. It looks similar to water retaining gel that pot plant growers use. It has doubled its mass overnight but still no gas is being given off.Smell has changed somewhat also

Comment: OK - it probably is the SCOBY. Hydrating it and allowing it to settle in for a few days is probably a good idea. During storage it shrivelled and dried to a large degree. Like this, the cell walls can be in a vulnerable state and the yeast/lacto grains need to be allowed to hydrate, swell and return to full metabolic activity over a period of time (eg a day or two at least). This can be done in dilute sugar and brew nutrient solution (aqueous). When the grains are fully regenerated add to the full ginger/sugar brew and make sure it is not too cold, eg. something above 16C is recommended.

Comment: I will give it more time.When it arrived there was aboul a level teaspoon of the jelly. is it possible that i just do not have enough yet ?

Comment: A teaspoon full is not a lot.  A tablespoon full is a better starting amount.  My advice would be to try to grow the initial spoon full to something more massive.  With sugar ginger and changes of water you should have enough in 3-4 weeks. The bug needs oxygen to grow,so foam the water when adding it.  Longer time taken to grow if colder that (say)  18C..

Comment: Thank you , i will give it more time. Bit disappointing considering i paid £15 for such a meagre amount.Mass has increased considerably now and PH is 4 so Lacto is going well. Did not know about the oxygen though, my alcohol brew is anaerobic i think.

Comment: Update, I know that my local water is about 320 TDS (hard) but measuring at my tap with my new meter shows over range at 2000 TDS. I suspect there is a water softener somewhere , could this be a problem ?

Comment: As a rule of thumb - if you can drink it then you can brew with it. Oxygen is necessary for growth, that is true for yeast. Lactobacillius can grow anaerobically. Both have anaerobic metabolic pathways,  so can exist without oxygen. Ginger scoby is more expensive than yeast but once it is going it grows well and is quite robust.  It is usually added to a brew mix for some days then strained out and added to a inew mix. It can be stored in the same liquid for up to a month.  It keeps well in the same liquid forc2weeks if fed with regular ginger and sugar.

Comment: I obtained a recent water analysis from the caretaker.Magnesium and, calcium are virtually non existant and sodium is very high. Does not seem to affect my ale brews but will try adding boild yeast extract and see what happens.

Comment: Generally speaking water high in sodium ions is "less than optimal" for human consumption.. I suppose there is an ion exchange column in the water system somewhere. I would recommend non softened mineral water,  out of a spring for example. Bottled water is another option.  I would recommend growing the SCOBY for a month using just organic ginger powder and sugar, although I am sure a little extract would not go amiss.

Comment: Just finished the first batch, i have had to discard it due to a very sour , unpleasant taste. Hardly a hint of ginger as well.The airlock bubbled well but there was no trace of a head on it.

Comment: Perhaps you could amend the question to tell what method(s) and recipes  were being used. Not so much for the yeast version but for your home made ginger bug and for the purchased ginger bug. May be we can spot a potential problem if given more detail. But whatever I would recommend rinsing the ginger SCOBY with (tap) water in a fine mesh small strainer and then add it to a new solution of sugar with some ginger powder - and thus attempt to grow it some more. Unlike yeast the SCOBY has to be present  in some quantity to initiate fermentation correctly.

Comment: Do you add any form of sugar with the ginger and lemon?

Comment: Yes i used 100g per litre in all cases.Three brews of three demijons each. First brew was usless.

Comment: @beerbug: would you like to condense all these comments and your experience into an answer for this, would be good to get a consice answer to the problem you were having.